# Can I create an object only used by each Thread in JNI?

Tags: multithreading, variables, java-native-interface

In Java I create some Threads, and they call the same native method like:

public native String go(String str);

In C Language, I have to make an object for each Thread, and the object is only used by each Thread.

Global reference cannot be used because it's shared by all Threads.

I don't want to create the object each time I invoke the JNI method.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Is it possible to pass the object from java and not create it in JNI?

Answer (score 1):

So you want thread-local Java objects at the JNI side? Just create a [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and store it in a global reference.